# Helpers in rspec

Tags: ruby, automation, rspec, helper

I have an rspec project that is used as a standalone app to test APIs. I want to find out what the best way is to define my API calls as helpers for code reusage.

The way I have it setup is I have a spec folder that contains a support folder and a test folder. In support I have a bunch of ruby files that are set up with ruby module/class that define API calls to be used in the specs.

example:

```
module Helpers
  class Project

    def add(name: nil)
      api_call_code_goes_here
    end

  end
end
```

This has worked for me, but I have been reading up on shared context in rspec and wonder if that is best practice or would work better for me.

example:

```
RSpec.shared_context "project" do

  def add_project(name: nil)
    api_call_code_goes_here
  end

end
```

Is there anyone with a similar rspec project that has helpers similar to mine? If so I would like to know how you are setting up your helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes in spec/support/helper file is best way for adding own code in rspec.......

I have added my login code in support helper file like

```
module Login
  module Admin
   # this method creates a admin login for request spec.
   def login_admin
    @admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin, password: '123456789')
    @current_admin = @admin
    visit new_admin_session_path
    fill_in 'admin_email', with: @admin.email
    fill_in 'admin_password', with: '123456789'
    click_button 'Sign In'
  end
end
```

Require this file in spec/spec_helper.rb

```
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

And in

```
config.include Login::Admin, type: :request
```

So I can used that super_admin_login method any request spec....

Comment: Everything you did is very similar to what I am doing, one question though. What is the "type: :request" in the config.include?

Comment: That type means that helpers only include for request spec. If u what for controller u can write controller. And if u skip that type attribute means u can used that helper in any spec.